# How to make Jetty load webdefault.xml when it runs in OSGi?

Tags: jetty, osgi, jetty-8

I'm running a Jetty 8.1.12 server within an OSGi container thanks to jetty-osgi-boot as explained in [Jetty 8](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_OSGi) and [Jetty 9](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/framework-jetty-osgi.html) documentation

I want to configure the default webapp descriptor (`etc/webdefault.xml`). When I define `jetty.home`, jetty picks up `etc/jetty.xml` but it does not load `etc/webdefault.xml`

I do not want to rely on a configuration bundle (through the `jetty.home.bundle` system property) because I want the config easily modifiable.

I do not want to rely on the `Jetty-defaultWebXmlFilePath` MANIFEST header for the same reason, plus it would tie my webapp to jetty.

The jetty-osgi-boot bundle contains a [`jetty-deployer.xml` configuration file](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-osgi/jetty-osgi-boot/jettyhome/etc/jetty-deployer.xml?h=jetty-8) with this commented-out chunk :

```
 <!-- Providers of OSGi Apps -->
  <Call name="addAppProvider">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot.OSGiAppProvider">
        <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
        ...
```

which does not work because the `OSGiAppProvider` class does not exist anymore.

Is there any other way to configure the webdefaults.xml file location ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : I could not have jetty 8.1.12 to load webdefaults.xml under OSGi.

After many hours of googling, source-reading and debugging, I came to these conclusions :

- The `Jetty-defaultWebXmlFilePath` MANIFEST header did not work as expected. It could not resolve a bundle entry path, only a absolute file system path. An absolute FS path was not a realistic option.
- Much of the configuration is hardcoded in `ServerInstanceWrapper` and the likes of `BundleWebAppProvider` so we cannot configure defaults descriptor location. This location ends up to the default, which is, IIRC, `org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml`.

I resorted to patching jetty-osgi so that it can read *some* configuration and apply it to `BundleWebAppProvider`. FWIW this hack is available on [github](https://github.com/gfouquet/jetty.project/tree/jetty-8.1.12-squash-fix)